# Change transaction isolation level for internal data binding of asp.net controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding

Is there a way to take control over sql-session settings or transaction isolation level for controls in asp.net that support data binding directly to sql?

For instance:

```
someRichDataControl.SqlDataSource.SelectStatement = "select 1, 2, 3";
someRichDataControl.DataBind(); // now the control will open connection and execute sql
```

Can I force the control to use, for instance, ReadUncommited isolation level (or Serializable?)

The only idea I have is to apply settings directly in sql, but if that's a reusable sql, then that's tight coupling between sql and my control ( need to create parameterized query-builder ).

Comment: well, where is it getting the connection from?

Comment: You could put your select command in a stored procedure and set the isolation level there perhaps.

Comment: @MarcGravell, idk If I understood you correct. I would have to decompile the control's sources to tell you exactly, but Im pretty sure it opens an ordinary ado sql-connection. So in my case it takes connection from iis connection pool )

Comment: After some inspection: yes, it internally uses `System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill`